# Determining primes in quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Given an algebraic integer $\alpha$ (not a unit) $\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt m),$ how to determine that $\alpha$ is a prime?

I know that the necessary condition is: *The norm of $\alpha$ is $\pm p,$ where $p$ is a rational prime*.    Is there a sufficient condition?

---

Edit:

The necessary condition which I wrote is theorem $9.24$ in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: That is not a necessary condition. If you have a prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ that is inert, its norm will be $p^2$.

Comment: Note that in general, the ring of integers of a quadratic number field does not have to be a PID, so a prime ideal might have two generators.

Comment: @CPütz I think that your comments are contradictory to the theorem in the attached image. Please tell me what am I missing here.

Comment: You might be confusing the meaning of "necessary" and "sufficient"? The Theorem 9.24 gives a sufficient condition, but as I wrote above, it is not necessary. I.e. it suffices for $\alpha$ to have norm $\pm p$ for us to know that it is a prime, but not every prime has norm $\pm p$ (inert primes don't), so it is not necessary.

Comment: At first you should not talk of primes in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$, only of primes in $O_K$. Then (for $\alpha\ne 0$) $O_K/(\alpha)$ is a ring with $|N_{K/Q}(\alpha)|$ elements so it is not too hard to check if it is an integral domain thus a finite field. In most cases we have an isomorphism $O_K/(\alpha)\to \Bbb{Z}[x]/(f)/(\alpha)$ and it suffices to check that $(\alpha)$ contains a prime number $p$ and $f_j(x)$ for some irreducible factor of $f\bmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

An element $\alpha$ in a quadratic field with discriminant $\Delta$ is prime if and only if one of the following conditions holds:

1. $N\alpha = \pm p$ for some prime number $p$;
2. $N\alpha = \pm p^2$ for some prime number $p$ such that
   $(\frac{\Delta}p) = -1$.